# Arbitrary Intersection of family of open sets

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused with the arbitrary intersection of a this family of open sets. Does $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-1/n,1-1/n)=\emptyset$ or $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-1/n,1-1/n)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Your second choice should be $\{0\}$, not $0$.

Comment: It was, OP just didn't escape the { characters.

Answer (score 5):

When $n=1$ the corresponding interval is $$\left(-\frac11,1-\frac11\right)=(-1,0)\;.$$ This interval does not contain $0$, so

$$0\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)\;.$$

On the other hand, $0$ is the **only** element of

$$\bigcap_{n\ge 2}\left(-\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)=\{0\}\;,$$

and

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)=(-1,0)\cap\bigcap_{n\ge 2}\left(-\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)\;,$$

so $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)=\varnothing\;.$$